# How to configure chrome to ask for aws profile type before logging in

Tags: amazon-web-services

While running the chrome via bat script to login to aws console, In Windows OS, it is directly logging into default profile rather than asking for which kind of profile to log into(like dev, stage profiles).
However in Mac OS, chrome is asking for which profile to login prior to entering into the console window with the corresponding selected profile.

Has anyone faced the similar issue in Windows OS and resolved to ask for profile before logging into console?

Comment: Are you asking how to [add profiles to Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824)?